# How to start my Android application when a link clicked from external app like whatsapp or facebook?

Tags: android, deep-linking, intentfilter

I have used deep linking concept using following intent filter in manifest file.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="test.myapp.com"
                android:scheme="http"
                />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This helps me to show my application when clicked on link in whats app,
but it shows other applications in list like chrome,Internet etc.
How can I make only to access my app directly after clicking link in other application like whats app.?

Answer (score 1):

My only idea is to add an intent filter, that starts your app if the device opens a special URL (for example www.your-project.com). Have a look on this 
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html) it explains all social sites linkage to your app.

If the user has your app installed, a click on the link will open your app. Otherwise the link will be opened by your default browser.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is only possible from Android 6.0 , in Android 6.0 you can bypass the Intent chooser dialog and directly launch your application on clicking on the link.

To do this, please check on this [App link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html) documentation. They have explained very well how to do it

and also you may have to make slight modifications in the intent filter as shown below by adding parameter `android:autoVerify="true"`

```
<activity ...>

<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```